# Indian visa for a Bangladeshi: how to deal with blacklisting?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, india, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi. I have already travelled to India three times. The last time, I travelled to Nepal by road from India, then came back to Bangladesh. After finishing my Indian visa validity, I applied for an Indian visa, but the embassy gave me a blacklisted seal on my passport. I applied again and they did the same.

How can I withdraw this seal and get the Indian visa?

Comment: Please clarify: you want to go to Nepal? Or you want to go to India?

Comment: If this is very urgent, please respond promptly.

Comment: The question is now clear, IMO, but I don't think there's any point reopening it just to close it again as a near-exact duplicate of the onle linked by @RedBaron.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I respectfully disagree: I think it's worthwhile to have the correct close reason and a prominent link to the question of which this is a duplicate. Otherwise the next person with a similar problem may come along, see this question, and write another duplicate question with more details. Then again, I'm not sure how much time and effort is required for a mod to clear the current close reason and re-close as duplicate (I assumed it would be fairly straightforward).

Comment: @Pont If it's as simple as a mod changing the close reason, then I agree that would be useful. I'll flag and see what happens.

Comment: Done. I had to reopen and re-close since there seems to be no way to seamlessly update the close reason. Thanks for flagging, keep up the good work. :)

Answer (score 2):

> it was about travelling to nepal by road from india

Please take the next U-Turn and plan your trip again. With a blacklist stamp you are not going through anytime soon.